# question about plotting from txt file datas

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is a problem when plotting datas from `txt` files. There are 7 columns in my `txt` file, and I want to use data from the last column and the third column (separately as x-axis and y-axis), but the command doesn't work.

The error is:

```
x = [row.split()[6] for row in data]
> IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code is:

```
x = [row.split()[6] for row in data]
y = [row.split()[2] for row in data]

index = [i for i,val in enumerate(x)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_xticklabels(x)
ax1.plot(index ,y, c='r')
leg = ax1.legend()
plt.locator_params(nbins=len(index)-1)
plt.show()
```

and this is the a part of my `txt` files.

```
01.05.2016  00:01:00    313 U   42491,00069 -1,87   01.05.2016 00:02

01.05.2016  00:02:00    313 U   42491,00139 -1,87   01.05.2016 00:03

01.05.2016  00:03:00    313 U   42491,00208 -1,87   01.05.2016 00:04
```

if necessary, the following code shows how I initialize the datas:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open("tesy=t.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.split('\n')
```

Comment: Are there any shorter/blank lines in your input?

Comment: Try printing row.split() result. You can see columns.

Comment: Once you split, you have 8 columns so the last one will be [7] index

Comment: Are you sure you are loading in the data correctly?

Comment: Please can you show us how did you initiallize `data` variabe?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks for your reply, yes, there are blanks in my txt file, but it will cost me lots of time if I delete them one row by one row.

Comment: @Azhy Thanks for your reply, and sorry for my delay replying, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your three lines of data in a file `file.txt` and based on your description, this is the plot I get by rewriting your code. You don't need additional variable called `index` to label your x-ticks. You can directly plot `x` and the x-tick labels will automatically be set. To access the last column, I am using the index `[-1]`. This avoids counting the columns and putting the index manually. I removed the legend because there was no legend defined by you in the plotting command.

```
file = open("file.txt", 'r')
data = file.readlines()
data[0].split()
x = [row.split()[-1] for row in data] # if no blank line in the file
y = [row.split()[2] for row in data] # if no blank line in the file
# x = [row.split()[-1] for row in data if row.strip()] # if blank lines in the file
# y = [row.split()[2] for row in data if row.strip()] # if blank lines in the file

index = range(len(x))
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x ,y, '-ro')
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your code just now, the graph shows, but there are some problems with xaxis, there are lots of overlapped y-values, I think it's because the xaxis are seconds units, but there are lots of days in txt file, if the xaxis is not the 'date & time' unit, then is the graph not perfect. So I changed `x = [row.split()[-1]` for row in data] to `x = [row.split()[6]` for row in data], then the graph is better. Although I don'T know the difference between -1 and 6, but that works after all. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this should go for your file, and read line by line, then extract the x value from the last column in each line and append it to the list x, and extract the y value from the 3rd column and append it to list y
After afterwards, you will have all your data (x and y) saved and lists, now you can plot

```
x = []
y = []
filename = '/data.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    x = [x.split(' ')[-1] for x in f.readlines()]
with open(filename) as f:
    y = [x.split(' ')[2] for x in f.readlines()]
```

This will lead to a list containing the value with `\n` which is referring to a new line

to avoid this, you can do

```
x = []
y = []
filename = '/data.txt'

with open(filename) as f:
    x = [x.split(' ')[-1] for x in f.read().splitlines()]
with open(filename) as f:
    y = [x.split(' ')[2] for x in f.read().splitlines()]
print(x)
print(y)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

The output will be

```
['00:02', '00:03', '00:04']
['313', '313', '313']
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tired your code, but this works not successfully on my computer, the error is :`x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1048575,) and (0,)` I think the command can not output the y-value on my computer.

Comment: in which line exactly ?

Comment: the last 3 lines are:
 `File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 242, in _xy_from_xy
    "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1048575,) and (0,)`

Comment: Thanks fot that, but there is still an error: 
  
  `File "C:/Users/AK6PRAKT/Desktop/Daten.sammeln.Aufgabe/neletxt.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    y = [x.split(' ')[4] for x in f.read().splitlines()]

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Thanks for that, but always the same error:
  `File "C:/Users/AK6PRAKT/Desktop/Daten.sammeln.Aufgabe/neletxt.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    y = [x.split(' ')[2] for x in f.read().splitlines()]

IndexError: list index out of range` I think maybe as @Bazingaa said, that I only need to write `x = [row.split()[-1] for row in data] `and 
`y = [row.split()[2] for row in data]`, and I have changed the last column of my txt file, I erased take `/` instead of the `Blank` now the graph shows.